# How do I handle Python XML-RPC output and exceptions?

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I have created a simple [Python XML-RPC](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) implementation, largely based on the examples.

However, it sends output like this:

```
foo.bar.com - - [13/Feb/2010 17:55:47] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

... to the terminal, even if I redirect standard out and standard error to a file using `>>` or `>`. I'm doing this with the following line:

```
python foobar 2>&1 >> foobar.log
```

It seems almost like it's not sending to standard out, but somewhere else.

Also, when an exception occurs on recieving a request, the whole application crashes with this error:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('1.2.3.4', 51284)
```

How can I handle this exception? I need to recover gracefully, and just log the exception message rather than the server crashing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're using the `SimpleXMLRPCServer` class from the examples. In that case, simply provide the parameter `logRequests` when creating it:

```
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000), logRequests = False)
```

That will suppress request logging.

As for the exceptions, they're logged in `BaseServer` (cf. source code of "SocketServer.py"):

```
def handle_error(self, request, client_address):
    """Handle an error gracefully.  May be overridden.

    The default is to print a traceback and continue.

    """
    print '-'*40
    print 'Exception happened during processing of request from',
    print client_address
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc() # XXX But this goes to stderr!
    print '-'*40
```

As you can see, the first part is written to stdout, which is why `&2>1` didn't work completely. If you want to suppress them, override or overwrite that method.

Comment: How would I redirect log requests to somewhere else? For example, an instance of `logging.getLogger()`. Also, how is the application crashing when the exception is printed?

Comment: As you can see in the quoted code ("SocketServer.py" from the standard library, which is used indirectly by `xmlrpclib`), the app does not crash when an exception happened, it just gets ignored. If you want to redirect such logs, you could write your own `BaseServer`/`BaseHTTPServer`/`SimpleXMLRPCServer` classes (deriving from each other), or simply overwrite the logging functions, e.g. `SocketServer.BaseServer.handle_error = yourLogHandlerWhichWritesToLogger`.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a shell redirection problem, not a python problem. 
When you say

```
python foobar 2>&1 >> foobar.log
```

You are *first* redirecting stderr to stdout, and then *second* redirecting stdout to foobar.log.
stderr does not get automatically redirected to foobar.log. stderr still points to the original stdout.

So instead do this:

```
python foobar >> foobar.log 2>&1
```

See also http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/syntax/redirection (search for "Multiple redirections")

Comment: I could never get the hang of output redirection ha. Maybe I never will... I use this a lot in my crontab, so maybe I should check that first in future for reference.